# Перевод int() в roman numeral

Tags: python, python-3.x

Выдает ошибку:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   
File "python", line 28, in <module>   
File "python", line 17, in change_number 
TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'.
```

Вот код:

```
numDict = {1:"I",2:"II",3:"III",4:"IV",5:"V",6:"VI",7:"VII",8:"VIII",9:"IX", 10:"X",11:"XI",12:"XII",13:"XIII",14:"XIV",15:"XV",16:"XVI",17:"XVII",18:"XVII", 19:"XIX",20:"XX",21:"XXI",22:"XXII", 23:"XXIII",24:"XXIV",25:"XXV",26:"XXVI",27:"XXVII",28:"XXVIII",29:"XXIX",30:"XXX"} 

key_mass = list(numDict.keys())
val_mass = list(numDict.values())



class Number:
  def __init__(self,number):
    self.number = int(number)

  def change_number(self,key_mass,val_mass):
    for i in range(1,len(key_mass)):
      for j in range(1,len(val_mass)):
        if self.number == key_mass[i] and i == j:
          self.number = val_mass[j]
      if self.number > len(key_mass):
        print("Your number is too big.")
        break
      if self.number < 1:
        print("Your number is too small.") 
        break  

    print(self.number)


number1 = Number(9)
number1.change_number(key_mass,val_mass)
```

Comment: Всё правильно, вы в строке `self.number = val_mass[j]` записываете `str` вместо `int`, вот сравнение и ломается

Comment: Во-первых, проверять на больше-меньше надо бы до всех циклов (и уж тем более не внутри цикла), а во-вторых, для чего вообще циклы, если все можно сделать в одну строчку?

Comment: self.number = numDict[self.number]

Comment: связанный вопрос [В чем заключается неисправность программы по переводу чисел типа integer в римские цифры?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/835823/23044)